# How to jump to different stack navigator and close previous one with react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation and have 2 distinct stack routers in separate files **AuthedRouter** and **NonAuthedRouter**.  They each have unrelated screens with no overlap.

AuthedRouter looks like:

```
const AuthedRouter = StackNavigator({
  Home : { screen: Home }
})
```

NonAuthedRouter.js looks like:

```
const NonAuthedRouter = StackNavigator({
  Signup: { screen : Signup }
  SignupTwo : { screen : SignupTwo }
})
```

In my App.js I check the user app status and in my render method return **NonAuthedRouter** if user needs to signup. My problem is how do I then navigate to the Home screen in the **AuthedRouter** once signup is done? Also I want to make sure its dont properly and that the **NonAuthedRouter** screens are 100% removed from memory/etc.

Thanks.

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/guides/philosophy

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having two StackNavigator, u can perform the same using just one.

```
const MainRouter = StackNavigator({
  Signup: { screen : Signup },
  SignupTwo : { screen : SignupTwo },
  Home : { screen: Home }
})
```

If the user already signed up, just navigate to Home Screen and the user cannot go back from Home screen because there is no screen in the stack.

If its a new user then navigate to Signup screen, then to SignupTwo screen and ones sign up is completely done just reset the stack and navigate to Home screen. Reset will clear the stack screen. Read react-navigation docs for further information

The way to reset a StackNavigator

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home'})
  ]
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is how I am Navigating to the "Drawer Stack" after I reset the previous "Login Stack, when I am navigating:"**

```
            export const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
                {
                    MyAccount: {screen: TabsStack},
                },


        export const LoginStack = createStackNavigator(
                {
                    Login: {screen: LoginPage},
                }
            );


        export const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
                Login: {screen: LoginStack},
                Drawer: {screen: Drawer},
            },
            {
                initialRouteName: 'Login',
                headerMode: 'none'
            },
```

then on "Login Screen" you do:
      on a Button Press/Click:

```
     <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signuptext} onPress={this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this)}>
                            <Text style={styles.signuptext}> Sign Up Now </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
```

you call the "onLoginSuccess" Method like this:

```
    onLoginSuccess = () =>{
            {
                const navigateAction = StackActions.reset({
                    index: 0,
                    key: null,
                    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Drawer' })]
                })
                this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)
            }
```

Note: This basically resets the "Login" stack while navigating you to the "Drawer" Stack. So now when you will press the back button, you cannot return to the Login Screen of the "Login Stack".